# Await multiple tasks to be shown in GUI

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, task-parallel-library, async-await

Suppose I have two resources `A` and `B`, both of which I want to show to my user, via MVVM (this == view model)

```
this.A = GetA();
this.B = GetB();
```

As soon as I start using TPL:

```
this.A = await GetAAsync();
this.B = await GetBAsync();
```

This starts to get `A`. When `A` is ready, it shows `A` and proceeds to do the same with `B` -- not a very good solution. Would be better to:

```
var taskA = GetAAsync();
var taskB = GetBAsync();
this.A = await taskA;
this.B = await taskB;
```

Now, this starts to get `A`, starts to get `B` and waits for `A`. When `A` is ready, it shows `A` and waits for `B`, until it is shown, too. **Looks good, but**, what if `A` sometimes takes much more time to load, than `B`?

How could I implement the following scenario:

- Start loading `A`.
- Start loading `B`.
- When one of them is ready, show it.
- When the other one is ready, show it, too.

### ?

Comment: There is also a good answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12932930/1033570, not many votes though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can schedule continuations on those two tasks separately.

```
var uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
GetAAsync().ContinueWith(t => this.A = t.Result, uiScheduler);
GetBAsync().ContinueWith(t => this.B = t.Result, uiScheduler);
```

This way, if this is a WinForms or WPF app, the continuations will be dispatched to the UI thread for you.

---

Also note that I didn't write any code for the calling thread to wait for those two tasks to be completed. If you were to block the calling thread (not recommended) and that thread happens to be the UI thread, then you will run into a dead-lock situation:

```
var taskA = GetAAsync().ContinueWith(t => this.A = t.Result, uiScheduler);
var taskB = GetBAsync().ContinueWith(t => this.B = t.Result, uiScheduler);
Task.WaitAll(taskA, taskB);
```

The last line will block the UI thread. And when the tasks try to dispatch the continuations on the UI thread (which is blocked), this will prevent the tasks from being completed.

Comment: It also looks like answer by @I3arnon throws us into this kind of deadlock, isn't it?

Comment: @RustemMustafin no, he is using `Task.WhenAll` which doesn't block the current thread, as opposed to `WaitAll`.

Comment: This option would swallow any exceptions.

Comment: @l3arnon no, if there is an exception, accessing `t.Result` will throw an exception within the continuation.

Comment: @ErenErsönmez Which would only fault the unobserved continuation.

Comment: @ErenErsönmez, unfortunately it's silverlight. I managed to get to know all this scheduler stuff on my own. Anyway, thanks a lot.

Comment: @RustemMustafin uh, silverlight :) I rolled back my changes and tagged the question.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest option is just to combine the async operation with the update itself and then you can start and wait for both operations, but when each completes it updates what it needs to. You can do that by "sticking" the update at the end of each method or create an async wrapper method like this:

```
async Task UpdateAAsync()
{
    A = await GetAAsync();
}

async Task UpdateBAsync()
{
    B = await GetBAsync();
}
```

```
await Task.WhenAll(UpdateAAsync(), UpdateBAsync());
```

---

Or, as svick suggested, instead of a wrapper method you can have a wrapper lambda expression:

```
Func<Task> updateAAsync = async () => A = await GetAAsync();
Func<Task> updateBAsync = async () => B = await GetBAsync();
await Task.WhenAll(updateAAsync(), updateBAsync());
```

Answer (score 2):

you could use the static Methods of the `Task` class in combination with await to prevent a blocking interface:

```
var taskA = GetAAsync();
var taskB = GetBAsync();

await Task.WhenAny(new [] { taskA,taskB });
//first task completed

await Task.WhenAll(new [] { taskA,taskB });
//all tasks completed
```

this solution gets more complicated if there are more tasks than only two, then you should look for a solution where `Task.WhenAll` fits your needs or use something like a Backgroundworker.

Comment: IMHO this is better than Eren's answer. +1 from me.

Comment: Actually, this is not better than `ContinueWith`: 1. It doesn't show which of tasks finished; 2. It does not scale to more tasks.

Comment: @RustemMustafin `WhenAny` returns the task that got completed. So it **does** show which task finished.

Comment: @Default, technically, you are correct. But I still won't agree with you, because I can't write `this.(what did load?) = Task.WhenAny(...)` and also let it do all the type stuff, because here we have `Task<AType>` and `Task<BType>`.

Comment: @RustemMustafin I think what they mean is: `var completed = await Task.WhenAny(new [] { taskA,taskB });` and then `if(completed == taskA) this.A = taskA.Result;  else this.B = taskB.Result;` and repeat this after the second `WhenAny`. I wouldn't prefer this, but it will work.

Answer (score 0):

There's an article over at MSDN that discusses this very problem. [Read it here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155756.aspx).

Basically you use the result from `WhenAny` to see which `Task` was completed and remove it from the list that contains the tasks. Then you repeat until the list is empty:

```
IEnumerable<Task<int>> downloadTasksQuery = ListOfTasks();
while (downloadTasks.Count > 0)
{
    Task<int> firstFinishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(downloadTasks);
    downloadTasks.Remove(firstFinishedTask);
    // process the result from firstFinishedTask
}
```

This also scales should there be more than 2 tasks.

Comment: This does not cover the case of different task result types. And so much arbitrary code for such an obvious requirement? I still prefer `ContinueWith`.